# How to update data in text every x second coming from phone state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the below flutter plugin related to phone state data for the user

https://pub.dev/packages/cell_info

similar to the below native kotlin plugin

https://github.com/mroczis/netmonster-core

so as for in the example in fluter plugin:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cell_info/CellResponse.dart';
import 'package:cell_info/cell_info.dart';
import 'package:cell_info/models/common/cell_type.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  CellsResponse _cellsResponse;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  String currentDBM = "";

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    CellsResponse cellsResponse;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      String platformVersion = await CellInfo.getCellInfo;
      final body = json.decode(platformVersion);

      cellsResponse = CellsResponse.fromJson(body);

      CellType currentCellInFirstChip = cellsResponse.primaryCellList[0];
      if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "LTE") {
        currentDBM =
            "LTE dbm = " + currentCellInFirstChip.lte.signalLTE.dbm.toString();
      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "NR") {
        currentDBM =
            "NR dbm = " + currentCellInFirstChip.nr.signalNR.dbm.toString();
      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "WCDMA") {
        currentDBM = "WCDMA dbm = " +
            currentCellInFirstChip.wcdma.signalWCDMA.dbm.toString();

        print('currentDBM = ' + currentDBM);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      _cellsResponse = null;
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _cellsResponse = cellsResponse;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: _cellsResponse != null
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                    'mahmoud = ${currentDBM}\n primary = ${_cellsResponse.primaryCellList.length.toString()} \n neighbor = ${_cellsResponse.neighboringCellList.length}'),
              )
            : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the response class coming from native code:

```
import 'models/common/cell_type.dart';

class CellsResponse {
  List<CellType> neighboringCellList;
  List<CellType> primaryCellList;

  CellsResponse({this.neighboringCellList, this.primaryCellList});

  CellsResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['neighboringCellList'] != null) {
      neighboringCellList = [];
      json['neighboringCellList'].forEach((v) {
        neighboringCellList.add(new CellType.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['primaryCellList'] != null) {
      primaryCellList = [];
      json['primaryCellList'].forEach((v) {
        primaryCellList.add(new CellType.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.neighboringCellList != null) {
      data['neighboringCellList'] =
          this.neighboringCellList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.primaryCellList != null) {
      data['primaryCellList'] =
          this.primaryCellList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

and this is the method channel class plugin:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CellInfo {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('cell_info');

  static Future<String> get getCellInfo async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('cell_info');
    return version;
  }

  static const MethodChannel _sim_info = const MethodChannel('sim_info');

  static Future<String> get getSIMInfo async {
    final String version = await _sim_info.invokeMethod('sim_info');
    return version;
  }
}
```

I want to create a timer or something something similar thats to update this data every x second from the plugin it self.

Comment: Have you tried using  `Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => initPlatformState())` in the `initState`, assuming your problem I guess this might help.

Comment: Or something like: `Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1)).take(1).listen((_) => initPlatformState())`